# How to retrieve the sql code from an Excel 2007 PivotTable

Tags: python, excel

I have a pivot table, which I want to recreate programatically through python. Is there way to retrieve the current sql code of the pivot table for me to use it in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this recently.  It might work for you.  It attempts to copy pivot cache and/or query table data for the active workbook to the clipboard.  It's surrounded by On Error Resume Next so if it doesn't find a particular piece of data it keeps going:

```
Sub Copy_Connection_Info_To_Clipboard()

Dim ptCache As Excel.PivotCache
Dim qtQueryTable As Excel.QueryTable
Dim strPtCacheInfo As String
Dim strQueryTableInfo As String
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Dim strConnectionInfo As String
Dim doConnectionInfo As DataObject

On Error Resume Next
For Each ptCache In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
    With ptCache
        strPtCacheInfo = _
        strPtCacheInfo _
        & "PivotCache #" & "Index: " & .Index & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                         & "SourceDataFile: " & .SourceDataFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                         & "CommandText: " & .CommandText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                         & "SourceConnectionFile: " & .SourceConnectionFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                         & "Connection: " & .Connection & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
    End With
Next ptCache
If strPtCacheInfo <> "" Then
    strPtCacheInfo = "PivotCache Info" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & strPtCacheInfo
End If

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If ws.QueryTables.Count > 0 Then
        strQueryTableInfo = "Worksheet: " & ws.Name & vbCrLf
        For Each qtQueryTable In ActiveSheet.QueryTables
            With qtQueryTable
                strQueryTableInfo = _
                strQueryTableInfo _
                & "QueryTable Name: " & .Name & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                & .SourceDataFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                & .CommandText & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                & .SourceConnectionFile & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
                & .Connection & vbCrLf & vbCrLf
            End With
        Next qtQueryTable
    End If
Next ws
If strQueryTableInfo <> "" Then
    strQueryTableInfo = "Query Table Info" & vbCrLf & strQueryTableInfo
End If

strConnectionInfo = strPtCacheInfo & strQueryTableInfo
If strConnectionInfo <> "" Then
    Set doConnectionInfo = New DataObject
    doConnectionInfo.SetText strConnectionInfo
    doConnectionInfo.PutInClipboard
End If

End Sub
```